# I want to add value from IDR class from Main using USD class with polymorphism in java

Tags: java

i got a trouble here, i want to add value in IDR class using method (**toIDR()**) from USD class. the function of the method is to convert USD to IDR and auto add the value to IDR. but when it success to convert, the value from IDR not increase and still at that value.
here is the code:
Currency code:

```
package Sources;

public abstract class Currency {
    private double value;
    public Currency() {
    }
    public Currency(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public abstract void addValue(double value);
    public abstract double getValue();
    public abstract void toIDR();
}
```

USD class code:

```
package Sources;

public class USD extends Currency{
    private double value;
    //we using the currency from date 24 April 2020
    //$1 USD = 15.400 IDR
    private final double nilaiTukarSekarang = 15400;
    IDR currency =  new IDR();

    public USD(double value) {
        super(value);
        this.value = value;
    }
    public double getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public final double getNilaiTukarSekarang() {
        return this.nilaiTukarSekarang;
    }
    @Override
    public void toIDR() {       
            this.value = this.getValue() * this.getNilaiTukarSekarang(); 
            currency.addValue(this.getValue());
    }
    @Override
    public void addValue(double value) {
        this.value += value;
    }

}
```

IDR code

```
public class IDR extends Currency{
    private double value = 0;
    public IDR() {
    }
    public IDR(double value) {
        super(value);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public void getIDR() {
        this.getValue();
    }
    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public void addValue(double value) {
        this.value += value;
    }
    @Override
    public void toIDR() {
        this.setValue(this.value);
    }


}
```

Main code:

```
package Sources;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Currency test = new IDR(500000);
        Currency check = new USD(30);
        System.out.println(test.getValue());
        check.toIDR();
        System.out.println(test.getValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should print the `check.getValue()` in your last call to `System.out.println`?

Comment: Also,it not generally recommended to use floating point types to represent currency because of the well known rounding issues.

Comment: I did it before adding check.toIDR() and I got the value(30). about the rounding issue, yeah I think so, but in this case, the floating-point still good enough to use.